# which is faster INSERT INTO Mysql or Compare-Arrays in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, benchmarking

I have a PHP script that Gets a Json (with 100 or more records) and I have to insert the data into a Mysql DB.

Every time we perform an Insert, we previusly delete all the records in the DB.

Is probably that in many times the Json came with the same data that is already in the database, and I dont want to perform the Insert if the data is exactly the same. So I came with this script that compare the Json with the Data in the DB:

PHP:

```
$j2 = json_decode($getJson, true); //decode the Json

$resultD = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT CONCAT(cod, '-', nro)  as CodNro from sales WHERE id=".$id);

if ( mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $rows[] = $r[0]; //store the old info into an Array
        }


        foreach ( $j2['data'] as $item  ) {
                $CodNro[] = $item['cod'] . '-' . $item['nro']; //store the New info into an Array
        }


        function leo_array_diff($a, $b) { // function that compare the arrays
            $map = array();
            foreach($a as $val) $map[$val] = 1;
            foreach($b as $val) unset($map[$val]);
            return array_keys($map);
        }

        $result1= count(leo_array_diff($CodNro, $rows)); // check the NewArray vs OldArray
        $result2= count(leo_array_diff($rows,$CodNro));  // check the OldArray vs NewArray


        if($result1==0 && $result2==0) {
            //exit cause there's nothing to insert or update
            exit();
        } else {
            // run mysql insert here
        }

}
```

At the end I Count the items in each array, and:

- If one of them is > 0 I go with the Delete and then Insert
- If they are both 0 (zero) y Exit the script

IMPORTANT: The script will consulted every 5 minutes in 10 diferent machines.

So... which path is faster and better for the Cpu Usage and the DB?